# Uncaught Syntax Error ... < , why would my browser think my index.html is a javascript file?

Tags: angularjs

Need some experienced eyes to tell me what's going on.

I got this nice message.

[image]

so when I dutifully click on `mainCtrl.js:1`, devTools show me this.

[image]

How in the world did my browser decide that my `index.html` is now **`mainCtrl.js`** ?

You can already see my index.html in the window above... It is a direct copy of [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scotch-io/mean-machine-code/master/17-user-crm/public/app/views/index.html).

...and here is just one of the script tags causing me this grief (they all give this same Syntax error)...

```
 <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
```

There is no minifying or grunt/gulp action happening at all, so what could be causing this confusion?

all the js files are loading fine too, according to my nice morgan log

[image]

Comment: Maybe an erroneous rewrite rule in the http server?

Comment: @RolandStarke - my mainCtrl.js file is an exact copy of         https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scotch-io/mean-machine-code/master/17-user-crm/public/app/controllers/mainCtrl.js

Comment: @GrasDouble - indeed my server seems wacked, but what is a rewrite rule? I've never encountered one, and the server is a direct copy of  https://github.com/scotch-io/mean-machine-code/blob/master/17-user-crm/server.js

Comment: Is this during development mode? What setup are you using? Such things can be caused by a middleware that rewrites all unknown requests to the index page to support the html5 history api for client side routing, e.g. https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Comment: it is in dev mode, and I just disabled all that  $locationProvider.html5mode(true) stuff... At least I got a new error now... I think I'm on the right track

Comment: @ajaegle you are right there is a catchall route that serves index.html. and I guess your Morgan log 2230 is the filesize? That explains why they are all the same if always index.html gets send

Comment: it's working now - thx all... it was that html5history mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record (answered in the comments): Some express middlewares can be the reason for such rewrites, especially when using the html5 history api for client side routing. (for example https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback - which by default only responds to urls not containing a dot.)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you have an error in your (presumably Express) routes.

You probably have a catchall that is serving the index.html file. Further up in your route definitions you need a route to serve your .js file.